# Disable bitlocker to add HDs?

Tags: raid, bitlocker

Machine has two HD in RAID 0 configuration and bitlocker enabled. I want to add two more HD as RAID 0 then mirror the two sets of drives as RAID 1. Do I need to disable bitlocker or unencrypt to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, since I presume, see the RAID is a hardware RAID

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I also assume that bitlocker shouldn't affect the RAID configuration. But part of the process is configuration in Disk Manager, not hardware. I just wanted some assurance from a disinterested party. I made the conversion this afternoon without disabling bitlocker. Everything went fine with only a couple minor bumps, and the drives are resynching now.